# alternating BackGround property of an element in WPF using dedicated XAML File

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

in css you can call from an html file any style and easily
via code alter some property of style in a given element

so in C# WPF i would like to place a menu button that
will allow to alter the backGround

the XAML below is "Sample1" , is currently hardcoded as-is, and applied within a  `<Window.Background>` scope, to current MainWindow.
how can i create Sample2..4,5 so that via `C#` code, say through the "Style" menu button created, i will be able to alter the BackGround of an element ?

where could i place the settings in an orderly manner?

```
    <LinearGradientBrush  EndPoint="1,0.5" StartPoint="0,0.5" x:Name="Sample1" Opacity="0.46">
        <GradientStop Color="#8F63BADF" Offset="0.117" />
        <GradientStop Color="#9D56B7C9" Offset="0.666" />
        <GradientStop Color="#9343C0DB" Offset="0.279" />
        <GradientStop Color="#E734ABDA" Offset="0.442" />
        <GradientStop Color="#927FE2E2" Offset="0.802" />
        <GradientStop Color="#E974CFC1" Offset="0.56" />
        <GradientStop Color="#D076C5EB" Offset="0.255" />
    </LinearGradientBrush>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create different styles in a `ResourceDictionary` and reference your ResourceDictionary in your `App.xaml`.

Then you can at any time from your code change the style of any element.

**Eg:**

```
<ResourceDictionary>
  <Style x:Key="Style1BackgroundRed" TargetType="{x:Type Window}">
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="Red"/>
  </Style>

  <Style x:Key="Style2BackgroundGradient" TargetType="{x:Type Window}">
    <Setter Property="Background">
      <Setter.Value>
        <LinearGradientBrush  EndPoint="1,0.5" StartPoint="0,0.5" x:Name="Sample1" Opacity="0.46">
         <GradientStop Color="#8F63BADF" Offset="0.117" />
         <GradientStop Color="#9D56B7C9" Offset="0.666" />
         <GradientStop Color="#9343C0DB" Offset="0.279" />
         <GradientStop Color="#E734ABDA" Offset="0.442" />
         <GradientStop Color="#927FE2E2" Offset="0.802" />
         <GradientStop Color="#E974CFC1" Offset="0.56" />
         <GradientStop Color="#D076C5EB" Offset="0.255" />
      </LinearGradientBrush>
    </Setter.Value>
  </Style>
</ResourceDictionary
```

**In your App.xaml:**

```
<Application.Resources>
  <ResourceDictionary Source="/WhateverFolderYouUsedForYouStyles/StyleDictionary.xaml"/>
</Application.Resources>
```

**From your Window code:**

```
public MainWindow()
{
  this.Style = (Style)Application.Current.FindResource("Style1BackgroundRed");
}
```

Same way you can find the other style if you want to change to that one.

Comment: yes i was palying around with some resource Dictionary (got the idea few hours ago...) and created rectangle type style, trageted as the rectangle fills main `Grid`. so i made few duplicates with minor color changes..(shades).. then i was inserting new Style from settings into a `List<Style>` on click step into next style, this is a `Window` creator i am starting..