# How to avoid switching <TabItem> in <TabControl>

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have a Form in which I have TabControl with few TabItems, but when I'm clicking on Tab, they are changing their position in TabControl. How to avoid this kind of situation?

```
<TabControl>
    <TabItem Header="Header1" Name="Tab1">
            <Frame Background="White" Name="sig1" Source="tabs/signal1.xaml" />
    </TabItem>
    <TabItem Header="Header2" Name="Tab2">
            <Frame Background="White" Name="sig2" Source="tabs/signal2.xaml" />
    </TabItem>
</TabControl>
```

This is my example of xaml code. I have much more tabs in TabControl property.  All the tabs from the same row shifts with the next ones tabs.

Comment: this is wpf not a winform

Comment: Yes, sorry. I've changed tag.

Comment: Is the selected tab binded to something?

Comment: No it's not. It looks like this ones. But I have about 20 TabItems and they shifting between each other

Comment: they dont change position for me, any code behind in the `TabControl.SelectionChanged`?

Comment: @Tatarinho I wasn't able to reproduce it can you give more details please

Comment: I don't have code behind TabControl.SelectionChanged.
It's just a lot of Tabs in TabControl. Maybe important information is that Tabs change their position when I change windows size and then they are not fit into one row.

Answer (score 0):

I guess when you have so many tabs then they are located in two/three rows. and when you click on a tab in the secound row then all of those tabs move to the first row. That is the normal behavior of TabControl. Have a look at this MSDN template for tabcontrol: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc645035%28v=vs.95%29.aspx. You can change the behavior in a template and use it in your project.

Comment: Where can I add some kind of examples?

Comment: Well, You have to implement it in your project as a ResourceDictionary, and reference it where you need it. One way of doing it is this way http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35377780/alternating-background-property-of-an-element-in-wpf-using-dedicated-xaml-file/35381814#35381814. Be aware that the example is for something else, but the principle is the same.

Comment: Instead of referencing it from the code, you can do it from XAML with Style="{StaticResouce YourStyleName}"

Comment: I don't have any idea how to create proper Style for this kind of situation. It's not working.

Comment: @Tatarinho  Unfortunately there is no other quick solution for this. You have to play with the template. Easiest would be to copy paste the whole template from MSDN, and modify it so it fits to your requirements.